# BlueJ and Input from keyboard

Tags: java, input, console, java-io, bluej

i have written the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Typer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Console cons;
       cons = System.console();
       boolean edition = true;
       if(cons == null)
       {
           edition = false;
       }
       if(edition)
       {
           String name = cons.readLine("Give your name: ");
           System.out.println("Your name is: "+ name);
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("There is no console!");
       }
    }
 }
```

i am using BlueJ and it doesn't prompt for an input. it just prints out there is no console! Any thougts? Thanks you!

When i compile and run the program at powershell it runs normally. the thing is different with bluej for some reason.

Comment: Maybe there's no system console? It then returns `null`.

Comment: When i compile and run the program at powershell it runs normally. the thing is different with bluej for some reason.

Comment: It's waiting for your input.. what happens? please explain

Comment: It only prints out the message i have typed if the cons variable is equal to null so it does't wait for input it just prints out there is no console. like it doesn't import Console from java.io or it doesnt create the object.

Comment: I think that like Eclipse, BlueJ doesn't support this. Try this [link](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.il/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html).

Comment: Thanks i think i will find what i need there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To input any value using BlueJ, I normally use the BufferedReader statement.
It goes like this, 
BufferedReader name=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
After writing this statement in the class or the method, you can input any value using the console.
Be sure to give this statement after asking for a value.
In case of integers-
int variable name= Integer.parseInt(name.readLine);

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution with Scanner and i finished most of the course i had with Powershell and Eclipse. Still Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that BlueJ has a View>Console or a View>Output window. I am fairly certain of that, but it's been a long time since I used Bluej. Anyhow, You can use a Scanner object. The Scanner is a good way of handling input and I think it is more commonly used for input. It is a part of the Java API and examples of how to use it can be found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

The code shown on the page is used to scan from a file, but the same approach can be used to get input from the console and then do something with that. When you run the code and wherever you see the output from the System.out.println call, the program should wait for you to enter something.